# Modify a specific value on a specific column with specific condition

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I need to modify column 4 to 11 if its current value is 0 (zero) and only if column 1 has a keyword "video".

```
pX23hdzzs2     20181020     0samp     11
pXDvideo32     20181020     0samp     0
pXDvideo32     20181020     0samp     11
pXDvideo32     20181020     0samp     11
pXUwezp882     20181020     0samp     0
pXDvideo32     20181020     0samp     11
pXD7Hedss2     20181020     0samp     11
pXDvideo32     20181020     0samp     0
pXDvideo32     20181020     0samp     11
pXDvideo32     20181020     0samp     0
```

I'm having trouble filtering column 1 as wildcard **video** with * is not being accepted.

Script I used was:

```
$ awk -F "\t" '$1=="*video*" && $4==0 {print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4}' filename > filename_new
```

Comment: Please show your script

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004788/how-to-change-a-value-on-a-specific-field-with-specific-condition-linux

Comment: Try `$1 ~ /video/` (regex match) in place of `$1=="*video*"`

Answer (score 0):

awk '$1 ~ /video/ &&  $4=="0" {print}' file

pXDvideo32     20181020     0samp     0

pXDvideo32     20181020     0samp     0

pXDvideo32     20181020     0samp     0

See if it solves your problem.